# webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs is not a function

Tags: node.js, selenium

I tried a simple Selenium headless testing code

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()).build();
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Work\projects\POCs\selenium\test\phantom\headless.js:3:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: PhantomJS has long been abandoned. Have you tried headless Chrome?

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks. I'll try headless Chrome